# Understanding memory ownership models in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I was reading about memory ownership models in C and came across the following example to explain memory ownership models in C.

```
 void Z(void) {
    void *buffer;

    while (!is_queue_empty(&queue)) {
        buffer = queue_pop(&queue);
        // do something useful
        free(buffer);
    }
}

void Y(void **buffer_p, int function) {
    switch (function) {
        // lots of cases
        default:
            enqueue(&queue, *buffer_p);
            *buffer_p = NULL; // "claim ownership"
            break;
    }

}

void X(void) {
    void *buffer = malloc(1024 * 1024);

    Y(&buffer, 3);
}
```

Could someone please explain, what does it mean when the function `Y` "claims ownership" as shown above? How does it claim ownership? Also what does it mean to set `*buffer_p = NULL` inside `Y` and then again call `free` inside `Z`?

Comment: Is "claims ownership" your words or somebody else's?

Comment: Unlike in Rust, there is no concept of "ownership" in C. So it is not quite clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @FiddlingBits My words

Comment: In C, there is no inherent ownership.  Anybody who has and address of a variable can modify it (with some exceptions of course).  If you want to introduce ownership, you'll have to do it yourself through Mutexes/Semaphores/etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this example "ownership" means who is responsible for freeing the memory that was allocated.  When memory is dynamically allocated with `malloc`, the address of that memory should be passed to `free` exactly one time.

Note that `X` passes in the address of `buffer` to `Y` that allows `Y` to change the value of this variable.  Inside of `Y`, it copies the allocated pointer into a queue memory structure.  At this point both this structure and the `buffer` variable in `X` contain a pointer to this memory.

If that was all that happened in `Y`, then there would be a question of where this memory should be freed.  The next line takes care of that by assigning `NULL` to the dereferenced parameter.  This sets `buffer` in `X` to `NULL`, so now `X` doesn't have to worry about this memory.  In other words, ownership of this memory was passed from `X` to the queue data structure.

If you then look at `Z`, you can see that it pulls an object off of the queue and calls `free` on that memory.

Comment: In addition the comment is misleading.   `*buffer_p = NULL; // "claim ownership"`.  More like Y releases ownership because it's now owned by the queue.  So in assigning the value NULL it means it's not expecting to use buffer_p again and is the queue to somehow free it later.

Comment: Doesn't setting up the value equal to NULL also make the pointer passed into queue as NULL?

Comment: @Amanda It does not.  The value contained in `*buffer_p`, i.e. the pointer returned from `malloc`, is stored in the queue data structure.  Then `*buffer_p = NULL` overwrites the value stored in `*buffer_p` which is the same as `buffer` in `X`, so now `buffer` no longer contains the return value of `malloc` but the queue does have it somewhere.

Comment: @Amanda It's the same as `int x = 4; int y = x; x = 0`.  Here, `y` still holds the value 4 even though `x` no longer does.

Comment: When I do `enqueue(&queue, *buffer_p);`, does `*buffer_p` create a new pointer to the memory allocated in `X`?

Comment: @Amanda `*buffer_p` evaluates to the value of the pointer contained in `buffer` in `X`.  That pointer value is passed to `enqueue` where it presumably saves it.

Comment: So when the pointer (or the address of the memory allocated in X) is passed to queue, then why does setting the same pointer to NULL not alter the pointer's value in queue? I am confused here.

Comment: @Amanda We're not setting the same pointer.  We're setting a *copy* of that pointer.  Prior to the assignment, there are two copies of the return value of `malloc`.  One is in the queue and one is in `buffer` in `X`.  The assignment clears the latter one.  Again, it's the same as the example I gave above with `int`.

Comment: Okay, how does a new copy gets created in the queue? Does passing like `*buffer_p` automatically create a new "deep" copy?

Comment: @Amanda `*buffer_p` is just a pointer value.  If you did `void *p = *buffer_p;` you would have a copy of that value.

Comment: Okay, so if it would have been `enqueue(&queue, buffer_p);` then it would be equivalent to passing the reference? And then setting up NULL in the subsequent statement would have altered the queue structure also?

Comment: @Amanda Yes, if you did that then the queue would be pointing to `buffer` in `X` instead of the malloced memory.

Comment: Is `free` equivalent to setting `NULL`? The way `Y` takes up the ownership is by setting the memory created  by `X` to `NULL`

Comment: @Amanda They are **not** the same.  Passing a malloc'ed pointer to `free` invalidates the memory it pointed to and makes that memory available for future allocations.  If any other pointer variables contain that value they are not allowed to use it.  In contrast, setting a pointer to `NULL` just sets that variable, nothing more.  Any other variables that contain that pointer value may still use it.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not provide any model of memory ownership other than, if you allocate memory with `malloc` (or related routines), the memory “belongs” to (is reserved for) the C program that allocated it.

You are free to design additional ownership models. In the code shown, the routine `X` allocates memory with `malloc`, and then it “gives” the memory to routine `Y`. `Y` records the address of the memory in a queue it maintains. If we view `Y` as part of a set of routines that manages things in this queue (with `Y` for adding things, `Z` for removing things, and possibly other routines), we can make a model where, once memory is given to this set of routines, those routines “own” the memory and are responsible for either eventually freeing the memory or transferring ownership to some other routines.

`Y` explicitly denotes its ownership by setting the pointer that `X` passed to it to `NULL`, in the statement `*buffer_p = NULL;`. This is not necessary to transfer ownership—ownership is a conceptual thing that can be transferred simply by understanding (hopefully conveyed through good documentation). Some people prefer to set pointers to `NULL` when they should no longer be used, because that is viewed as a means of avoiding bugs when a pointer is inadvertently used when it should not be.